# Ender 6 un-modded loud retraction sound

Tags: retraction, creality-ender-6

Newly built Ender 6 printer makes a loud whine or beep for every retraction, print quality not affected, but is very annoying and louder than the rest of the printer.

Is this normal or do I need to grease or lubricate extruder gears?

Comment: Have you tried to isolate **where** the sound is coming from? It may be the filament rubbing on part of the printer itself.

Comment: Hi Owen, can you post a video link?